# angular-oauth2-oidc is not setting access_token

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid, angular-oauth2-oidc

I was following the getting-started guide for the angular-oauth2-oidc library, but the only thing it stores is the `nonce` value, the `access_token` doesn't appear anywhere.

This is the configuration I have for `AuthConfig`.

```typescript
export const AUTHCONFIG: AuthConfig = {
    loginUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/', //localhost:4200/
    clientId: 'the id of my angular app registered in azure',
    resource: 'the id of my web api in nodejs also registered',
    oidc: true,
    requireHttps: false // this is for testing in localhost
};
```

My `app.component.ts` has the following:

```typescript
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {this.loadConfig()}
     loadConfig(): void {
         this.ouathService.configure(AUTHCONFIG);
         this.ouathService.tokenValidationHandler
                          = new JwksValidationHandler();
         this.ouathService.token.setStorage(localStorage);
     }
}
```

In my `login.component.ts` I have:

```typescript
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {}
    login(): void { this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();}
}
```

After the user gets redirected here, I can see in the url the params of access_token and etc.

But when I go to localStorage the only thing I can see is `nonce` and its value, but not the `access_token`. I've already tried to print it in the console and I receive `null`.

This the url I get back: `http://localhost:4200/#access_token=thetoken&etcparams`.

Comment: Are you sure that library is compatible with Azure AD?

Comment: @juunas yeah, I saw this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSqREkxe2z0. I have already solved my problem, now I can see the access_token, I have a new error where it is saying that I have a wrong issuer so it can't validate the token. I set my issuer property to https://login.microsoftonline.com but it keeps saying that is a wrong issuer.

Comment: where was the error and how did you fix it? i also can't access the token after returning from login page - even tho it is set as a paremeter in the url.

Comment: @Entertain The error was that I was not setting the issuer and jwks properties in my AuthConfig, which apparently are required in order to work properly, once you fill those props, It should work fine :).

Comment: @Entertain Did it work for you friend?

Comment: @OttoCheley I am having same issue. I am also setting issuer and jwks properties but no luck.

Comment: @shobhitvaish How is your configuration?

Comment: @OttoCheley Here is how it looks like. I am using identity server 4

    this.oAuthService.issuer = 'http://localhost:58117';
    this.oAuthService.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:4200';
    this.oAuthService.clientId = "angular_web_spa_external_auth";
    this.oAuthService.scope = "openid profile email taaable_api";
    this.oAuthService.customQueryParams = { acr_values: 'idp:Google' };
    this.oAuthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();

Comment: The problem is in you issuer, you must place a url there that is not localhost, you will find the issuer and all the other keys in the following url https://login.windows.net/{tenant-name or id}/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: @OttoCheley Looks correct to me 
  {"issuer":"http://localhost:58117","jwks_uri":"http://localhost:58117/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks","authorization_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/connect/authorize","token_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/connect/token","userinfo_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/connect/endsession","check_session_iframe":"http://localhost:58117/connect/checksession","revocation_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/connect/revocation","introspection_endpoint":"http://localhost:58117/conn .........

Comment: Believe I tried using localhost and it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173007/discussion-between-otto-cheley-and-shobhit-vaish).

Comment: Was this ever figured out? I'm having an exact same problem :)

Comment: Have you checked the generated `response_type` if it contains `token`? `access token` is only returned when `response_type=token` or `response_type=id_token token` actually.

Answer (score 0):

@Otto Cheley you dont need to add JWK validator.

```
    export class AppComponent {
     constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {this.loadConfig()}
     loadConfig(): void {
         this.ouathService.configure(AUTHCONFIG);
        // this.ouathService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
         this.ouathService.token.setStorage(localStorage);
     }
    }
```

Try with commenting tokenValidator